# Solving two ODEs together

Tags: differential-equations

Why does Mathematica not give any output when I am trying to use [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) to solve these two equations?

```
Θ[y_]=c1ⅇ^A1y+c2ⅇ^(-A1y); Θp[y_]=1/(s+ϵ)(c1ⅇ^A1y+c2ⅇ^(-A1y));
DSolve[{u''[y]-(s+M)u[y]+ksα(up[y]-u[y])+GrΘ[y]==0,1/β1 up''[y]-s up[y]- 
α(up[y]-u[y])+GrΘp[y]==0},{u,up},y]
```

Comment: After a minute this `Θ[y_]:=c1*E^A1y+c2*E^-A1y; 
Θp[y_]:=1/(s+ε)(c1*E^A1y+c2*E^-A1y); 
DSolve[{u''[y]-(s+M)*u[y]+k*s*α*(up[y]-u[y])+Gr*Θ[y]==0, 
1/β1*up''[y]-s*up[y]-α*(up[y]-u[y])+Gr*Θp[y]==0},{u,up},y]` gives me a solution with version 12. Have I made any mistake trying to guess what characters you are using or where to put the `*`? Restart Mathematica and scrape-n-paste that into the notebook and evaluate it and see if you get a solution.

Comment: Dear bill thanks thanks thanks, your advice works.